# Getting value from attribute as text. XPATH 1.0

Tags: xpath

I have

```
<div title='one'></div>
```

How can I get "one" as a text, but not as a DOMAttribute?

When I use

```
//div/@title
```

I recieve

```
title='one'
```

But I need only "one". Is it possible?
Stuff like this doesn't work:

```
//div/@title/text()
```

P.S. Using XPATH 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Use `string(//div/@title)` to select the string value.

Comment: There is no other way? I just have this function disabled.

Comment: Well, if you use `//div/@title` in a string context like `concat('', //div/@title)` then you will get a string as well. I am not sure what you mean with a function being disabled, if you use XPath, why would a function be disabled? And of course with most XPath APIs, if you use `//div/@title` to select the attribute node, you can then get the attribute's value with DOM specific accessors/methods. So you might need to elaborate in which environment you use XPath.